# Smooth aggressive values in the list

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, collections

I think it's kind of new question, where we didn't have solution. I need to implement some kind of smothering for a very big values in a list of numbers. For ex.

```
list = np.array([3, 3, 3, 15, 3, 3, 3])
```

I have made very simple implementation, with smothering such values. What I have tried so far.

```
def smooth(x, window, threshold):
    for idx, val in enumerate(x):
        if idx < window:
            continue
        avr = np.mean(
            x[idx-window:idx])

        if abs(avr - val) > threshold:
            x[idx] = avr + threshold

print(smooth(list1, 3, 1))
# [3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3]
```

In this case, everything works Ok, but taking another example, I need to smooth data in a another way(gaussian smooth for ex).

```
list = np.array([3, 3, 3, 15, 15, 15])
print(smooth(list, 3, 1))
# [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3]
```

Because `window` moving from the left to right, I don't know `norm` of next value. Of course I can evaluate window for this numbers from both directions, but just wondering about right ways of doing that, or common technique.

Comment: What would be the output for `np.array([3, 3, 3, 15, 15, 15])`?

Comment: @DanielMesejo Is it clear?

Comment: The result have a different size is that intended?

Comment: @DanielMesejo Maybe I need to add Paint screenshots, to give you understanding of `mean` of the list with few numbers?

Comment: Might be better to smooth using a moving average (easily calculated with a moving window).

Comment: Can you write more about purpose of action "smooth aggressive value in the list"? What you would do further with data you get after that operation? How do you define which values are "aggressive"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise against implementing 1D filtering yourself, since

- you are likely to introduce artifacts into your data when taking a naive approach (as using a rectangular filter shape like you did in your code snippet).
- you are unlikely to come up with a implementation remotely as fast as existing implementations, which have been optimized for decades
- unless you are doing it for autodidactic reasons, it is a classic example of wasting your time by reinventing the wheel

Instead make use of the rich variety of existing implementations, available e.g. in the scipy package. You can find a nicely illustrated usage example here: [Smoothing of a 1D signal (Scipy Cookbook)](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/SignalSmooth.html)